# Connection reset by peer: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Getting an Apache error when I try to POST using Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4:

> (104)Connection reset by peer: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

Post requests work with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have similar issue. Any one can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567486/errnoeconnreset-connection-reset-by-peer-ruby-on-rails-using-rest-client

Answer (score 4):

According to [Apache's Bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44782), this is by design. From the linked report:

> All it takes to produce the above error with Apache is to send a post to a cgi script that does not handle the post data.

Even though you say the script works in earlier versions, I'd suggest verifying your CGI script is actually handling the post data.

You might also use something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to directly examine what is being posted and then trace it through on the Apache side.

## Workaround

(Edit) [One commenter](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44782#c6) in the aforementioned bug report suggested an easy workaround:

> Simply read all the data from standard input and throw it away immediately without any further handling or just close the stdin file handle in your cgi script and you are done.